# Why is print_r return value and 1

Tags: php

My class getting the name

```
public function getGameName($gameID){
    $gameIDValid = false;

    try {
        $db = database::databaseConnect();

        $getGame_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT gameID, shortTitle FROM games WHERE gameID =:gameID');
        $getGame_stmt->bindParam(':gameID', $gameID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $getGame_stmt->execute();

        if($getGame_stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            $gameIDValid = true;
        }

        $db = NULL;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $gameIDValid = false;
    }

    return $gameIDValid;

}
```

From my class doing error checking

```
public function validategameID($gameID) {
    $validGame = userValidation::getGameName($gameID);
    if($validGame === false){
         return 'Problem adding your game';
    }
}
```

My Validation code:

```
$validatedGameID = $validateUserInput->validategameID($gameID);
die($validatedGameID);
```

If I choose a wrong Game ID I get the error message.  However when I use:

```
    die(print_r($validatedGameID));
```

I get the following output:

```
Problem adding your game1
```

If I use the correct Game ID I can't execute any other code after the:

```
die($validatedGameID);
```

Can anyone please help?  Why is the function returning a `1` at the end of the error message when I use `print_r` and why can't I execute any code after the `die` even with a correct game id?

Comment: Have you checked the `print_r` documentation?

Comment: "why can't I execute any code after the `die`" --- because `die` stops the script execution (also see its documentation).

Comment: use the second parameter for print_r() to make it return the string rather than print it to screen.

Comment: @IvoP it makes no sense.

Comment: ah. Willem is using die() to debug code? die( ) is equal to exit( ). It's like "sterf( )" (should you understand Dutch)

Answer (score 3):

The print_r function prints all its output to the screen and returns true as a value. If you want it to return the data rather than print to screen add true as the second parameter

```
$dump = print_r($var, true);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: They have a scalar value. Using `print_r` makes totally no sense there. The code you provided in this particular case is equivalent to `$dump = $var;`

Comment: Thanks, I added `else {return true;} ` in my validation method and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
die(print_r($validateGameID));
```

performs the following steps:

1. Call `print_r($validateGameID)`. This prints the value of `$validateGameID`, because that's what `print_r()` does when called with 1 argument.
2. Call `die()` with the return value of `print_r()`. `print_r()` returns `TRUE` when called with 1 argument. This performs the following steps:

   1. Print `1`, because `TRUE` becomes `1` when converted to a string.
   2. Exit the script, because that's what `die()` does (it's just an alternate name for `exit()`, but by convention used when exiting because of an error)

So all together it prints `$validateGameID`, then prints `1`, then exits the script.

Since it exits the script, nothing after it executes.

You can give `print_r()` a second argument to make it return the formatted version of its argument, rather than printing it:

```
die(print_r($validateGameID, true));
```

Or you could simply call `print_r()` and `die()` seperately:

```
print_r($validateGameID);
die();
```